# What was Nakamura thinking with 62...g5 against Carlsen in Senquefield Cup 2018 rd. 9?

Tags: endgame

[image: 62...g5?]

I (a 2300 player) would never consider 62...g5 in this position giving White a protected passed pawn.  Nakamura either thought it was a drawing method, or the toughest defense, but Carlsen showed there is a clear winning plan for White. 62...g5 strikes me as a clear mistake but are other moves easier for White to win against?

I am trying to understand this decision by a 2800 player, thanks.

Comment: Actually, this is a very good question. I wondered it myself and the chessbase reporter said: "A shocker! We will never really understand why Nakamura decided to commit hara-kiri here." (https://en.chessbase.com/post/sinquefield-cup-2018-round-9)

Comment: One motive would be resolving the kingside tension. Though as you said, White gets a connected passed pawn, so I don't know whether ...g5 is good.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that Naka doesn't push g5 and instead waits (with for instance Rb7). Then it is white who can play g5+, taking advantage of the pin on the 6th rank. If black plays Kg6, then Kg4 and h5+ is unstoppable. It is clear that white is making progress. If black instead plays Kh5, then gxf6 hxf6, Rxf6 and black has lost a pawn and his king is completely stuck in a box. Rf5+ might be a possibility (taking on e5), black still cannot move the a pawn (due to an immediate Ra6 getting behind it), and again white has clearly made progress.

I believe Naka was sure that these lines were easy wins for white. Better to make the committal, but potentially holdable, g5 move, and try and hold the position with a static pawn structure, than sit and wait only to lose in a few moves.

Comment: 62...Kh7 63.g5 fg5 64.hg5 Re7 is another option.  Sure White continues to squeeze but these lines appear to be unclear still while g5 is a clear loss I believe.  Did Naka just not know this ending?

Comment: g5 not a "clear" loss if you believe you can stop white from penetrating. If so, this ending could be transformed into a philidor position. Unfortunately, you cannot stop an eventual king penetration...

Comment: This is definitely the why of nakamuras decision